# Unable to see files and folders of Sharepoint site when connected via WebDav, unable to download multiple files or folders

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a Sharepoint site I have access to. The site URL looks like this:
https://[domainname.com]/sites/lib-repository/[site-name]

When I log in, I am auto redirected to:
https://[domainname.com]/sites/lib-repository/[site-name]/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

I am not the administrator.

I am able to see folders and files when I use a web browser. I am using macOS 10.13 and Safari. When I click on individual files, at the top of the site, a tab "FILES" will appear, and I will be able to click on the option "Download a Copy" under this tab.

However, when I click on folders, the "Download a Copy" option is greyed out.

I am trying to find a way to download more than one file at once or a folder or few. I have googled for options, and found something along the lines of connecting with WebDav.

However, when I tried to connect to the site using Finder > Connect to Server > [input the same URL], and use the same credentials as I did with the web browser to sign in, *I can connect*, but can't see any files and folders.

Is this something that the admin must allow? How can I solve this if I can’t contact the admin?

P.S. The site's running Sharepoint Server 2013.

Comment: it *should* work the way you describe working with WebDav in finder. However I would guess that this is a permission issue. Could you get an admin to try her credentials on your mac and see if the result is the same?

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot download the whole folder in Sharepoint, there is not such functionality out of the box.
2. It seems there are issues with trying to connect using webDAV from MacOS as it requires basic auth turned on. Try tu use Microsoft Document Connection

> For Mac OS:
>
> Unfortunately, it is not possible to work with SharePoint documents
>   through WebDAV on Mac OS. The common scenario is: you can connect
>   successfully, however, you cannot copy or edit documents on the site.
>   This occurs because Mac OS requires Basic Authentication to be enabled
>   on the site to manage files and folders. In the hosted Exchange
>   environment, we have Integrated Windows authentication enabled and
>   cannot change this setting because of security risks.
>
> However, there is a workaround for connecting to a SharePoint site on
>   Mac OS. This application is called Microsoft Document Connection.
>   Note: Make sure that Office 2008 for Mac is upgraded to Office 2008
>   for Mac SP2 (version 12.2.0). To do this, use Microsoft AutoUpdate

REF: https://kb.intermedia.net/Article/1603##macos